# Alternative to `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, scheduled-tasks

#### My intended process:

1. This is on a VM running Windows 2008 Server r2
2. Windows Task Scheduler kicks off an Access db with a startup macro.
3. The VBA script generates and saves some highly customized emails.

#### The problem:

This scripts works just fine when I manually open the db and run the script.  But when I use the task to start it, I get error 429 'ActiveX component can't create object' on the 2nd line of:

```
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Why does this throw an error when initiated by the task scheduler, but run fine manually?

#### About the Task:

1. On the General tab, I have these settings:
   a. Under my account
   b. with the highest privileges
   c. only when I'm logged on
2. The action itself opens Access 2010 aka Office14 with the DB's path & name, /x, and macro name as parameters.  When I run this as a batch file, there are no problems.
3. I know almost nothing about this OS or the modern task scheduler, but I can always learn.

#### Update

Found an [MS Support](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;257757) article on this very subject. It specifically states that `CreateObject` and `CoCreateInstance` will fail will the above error message if used in this way.  However, no alternative is given.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 3):

What fixed it for me was to **run Outlook as Administrator**.

Answer (score 2):

No Office app, Outlook included, can be used from a service. Even if the task can interact with the desktop, the COM system will not let you connect to a running COM object (Outlook is a singleton) since the security contexts are different.

You can use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), CDO 1.21 (deprecated and is no longer updated or installed) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author - use the [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of objects) - all of these load the Extended MAPI system in-proc instead of connecting to an out-of-proc COM object (exposed by outlook.exe).

Comment: Redemption sounds hopeful, especially since it can be used with Exchange.  Alternatively, can I get the task scheduler to run this as a regular desktop program? There's no need for it to be run as a service.

Comment: Task Scheduler may or may not work, in my experience it all depends on the Outlook/Windows version and UAC.

Answer (score 1):

When sending email messages from VBA code I have always preferred to use CDO instead of trying to automate Outlook. For some sample code to send email messages via CDO, look [here](http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm).

Comment: Keep in mind that CDO 1.21 has not been updated for over 10 years and is no longer installed by Outlook (as of Outlook 2010)

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko That may be true, but `cdosys.dll` is still included in a vanilla install of Windows (including both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the .dll on 64-bit Windows). It may not be the latest technology, but it still seems to get the job done.

Comment: cdosys.dll has nothing to do with Outlook: it lets you send messages using straight SMTP. While that may work fine for some purposes, the biggest disadvantage is that the sent message will not be created/saved in the Sent Items folder in Outlook unless you create a fake message there explicitly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to your problem, The VBScript interpreter (cscript.exe/wscript.exe) comes with a 64-bit version of Windows and a 32-bit version.

What I did was installed the Office x86 then uninstalled then installed x64 tested emails from task scheduler working, then I reinstalled x86. I did restart after each install and uninstall. When you install the x64 and x86 version of office it will install both versions cscript.exe/wscript.exe x86 and x64. Which in the end allows you to send a mail from task scheduler (Tested on Windows 10).

Thanks